# Specific events from Token Program via Web Socket

Tags: mint, websocket, initialize, token-account

I'm attempting to use the programSubscribe method to listen for specific types of Token Program events, namely "initializeMint".  Essentially, I want to know about the creation of token accounts before they mint.

In explorer, I can see that specific event associated with the Token Program, as well as the actual account creation, but when I listen to all events from the program all I see are events with type="mint" or type="account".  Should I not expect to see the exact phrase "initializeMint" in the emitted event?

Clearly I'm misunderstanding something or there are assumptions that aren't clear to me yet.  Are all of these events with type="account" the creation of token accounts?  The documentation on Web Sockets doesn't go into much detail on the payload.

devnet txn: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/rBrU8B8FDNAan6wYWvo9N2xfNLtMwXxNQned8Bmjgm7JWHfje2jJKXTE4mWqf7mBz43G82UpDkXh6W2iJu3P9zm?cluster=devnet

And the docs I have been referring to:
https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/programsubscribe

I also looked at [logsSubscribe](https://solana.com/docs/rpc/websocket/logssubscribe) but that was much more verbose and gave me the sense that there were other scenarios when InitializeMint appeared in the instructions.

Any guidance, link to robust documentation on event payloads, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `programSubscribe` endpoint specifically gives *account* updates when one of the accounts owned by the program changes:

> Subscribe to a program to receive notifications when the lamports or data for an account owned by the given program changes

This means that you'll get all of the accounts, both `"mint"`s and `"account"`s, and *not* the instructions that were executed, like `initializeMint`.

You have two options:

- Keep using `programSubscribe`, and count that a mint has been created when its `supply` is equal to 0. Note that this approach is fallible, because it's  possible for a mint to be initialized *and also* for tokens to be created within the same transaction, so you'll miss those creations.
- Use `logSubscribe` and parse for the following two lines, as shown in your sample transaction:

```
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]",
  "Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint",
```

I would go with the second approach since I know it'll always work, whereas the first one is more brittle.

Comment: Thanks, Jon.  This is where I was going with it.  While the log event payloads can be verbose, logSubscribe also offers much more flexibility and extensibility.  For example, if the boilerplate RPC code is agnostic of the data being parsed, I could simply pass, at request/subscribe time, a parser method to handle the result.